# How do you redo a git rebase -i step?

Tags: git, rebase

I inadvertently did a few changes I didn't want to on an interactive [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) step.  I was wondering how do I replay the step again so it is back with all the merge conflicts and what not.

I am presuming it is something to do with REBASE_HEAD and ORIG_HEAD but not exactly sure how.

Comment: You can always `git rebase --abort`

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git cherry-pick REBASE_HEAD
```

Comment: But you are in the middle of a rebase... and then you try to run `git merge`? I would assume you should run `git cherry-pick REBASE_HEAD` as merge would try to do something very different.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file you edited in a way you actually don't want and would like to get it back without touching other files (as `git reset --hard` does), you might consider:

```
git checkout -m some-file
```